# Enable submit when all form items are valid

Tags: javascript

I need some help with something... say I have the following form...

```
<form name="" id="" method="" action="">

    <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="text" id="text3" name="text3" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="text" id="text4" name="text4" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="let's go" disabled="disabled" />

</form>
```

Now I want to have a simple script to enable the submit when the values of the text boxes are not an empty string or null...

So I have something like this.. which I will bind to the window.onload

```
 function enableButton(){

    var formitemsArray = ['text1','text2','text3','text4'],
       i;

        // Loop through all items
        for(i=0;i<formitemsArray.length;i++){

            // validate the length on the keypress...
            formitemsArray.onkeypress = function(){

                // loop through all the items again
                for(j=0;j<formitemsArray.length;j++){

                    if(formitemsArray[j] == "" || formitemsArray[j] == null ){
                        // return false or something???
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

}
```

Now I think I'm on the right lines to a solution but I'm getting lost when trying to make sure that all the items are greater than a zero length string as I'm returning false too soon. Can someone set me straight please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to event bubbling!

This does the following: listen to an event (onkeypress) on the whole element and all its children! Which means you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById('form-id').onkeypress = function(e) {
    var text1 = document.getElementById('text1'),
        text2 = document.getElementById('text2'),
        text3 = document.getElementById('text3'),
        text4 = document.getElementById('text4')

    if (text1.value.length > 0 &&
        text2.value.length > 0 &&
        text3.value.length > 0 &&
        text4.value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('submit-button').disabled = false
    }

    // As an aside, for later: if you want to get the element
    // that triggered the event, you have to do the following
    // to be cross-browser:
    var evt = e || window.event, // IE doesn't get the event passed by argument
        target = e.target || e.srcElement // 'target' is official, old versions of FF used 'srcElement'

    // With the 'target' variable, you can now play.
}
```

There is another more generic solution, but it might not fit your needs (note that it requires a `forEach` shim:

```
// Declare a counter variable
var count = 0
document.getElementById('form-id').onkeypress = function(e) {
    // Get all the inputs!
    var inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('input')

    // Now loop through all those inputs
    // Since a NodeList doesn't have the forEach method, let's borrow it from an array!
    [].forEach.call(inputs, loopThroughInputs)
}
function loopThroughInputs(input) {
    // First check the type of the input
    if (input.type === 'text') {
        // If the value is correct, increase the counter
        if (input.value.length > 0) {
            count++
        }
        // If the 4 inputs have increased the counter, it's alright!
        if (count === 4) {
            document.getElementById('submit-button').disabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

And now this code was proposed by [@Esailija](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3173326#3173326), and it **is** way better and cleaner. However, it also requires [ES5-Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) (for the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method):

```
document.getElementById('form-id').onkeypress = function(e) {
    var inputs = [].slice.call( this.querySelectorAll( '[type=text]') );
    document.getElementById('submit-button').disabled = !inputs.every(function(input){
        return !!input.value;
    });
}
```

*(This guy is brillant, just don't tell him)*

Comment: That's brilliant... my approach was wrong, I now see my folly. Cheers for the help!

Comment: I just edited for a more generic solution, I didn't test it though!

Comment: I didn't think to check for type in my solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this... One would be to keep the button enabled but use javascript to check the validity of the form data upon submission. The benefit to this is that the validation code is only run once, when the user clicks submit and is expecting his data to be validated (at least I do) .

```
function validateForm() {
  var formElement = document.forms[0]; // you didn't give me a name
  for(var i = 0, l = formElement.elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
      if( formElement.elements[i].value.length === 0 ) {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

The other way is *live validation*, which would validate each input onBlur (focus lost). This method has the benefit of showing the user in real time what values are bad, however this can be very resource heavy depending on the number of form elements and the way you introduce the check.

Personally I would go with my first suggestion; however with that said if you choose to validate each element, I would do so like this:

```
  var formElement = document.forms[0]; // you didn't give me a name
  for(var i = 0, l = formElement.elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
      formElement.elements[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
           if( this.value.length === 0 ) {
              alert('this input is invalid');
           }
      }, false);
  }
```

The latter method also requires you hold onto a 'state' variable to determine whether or not the form is valid upon submission, or check all the values again.

Hope this sheds some light, and I hope my code examples help some.

Comment: +1. His approach from the beginning may not be the best one, yours sure would be better. Why not the `onblur` event on the whole form tho?

Comment: because I didn't think about it :P

Answer (score 0):

If possible use jquery validation plugin instead of re-inventing the code, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation its so easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9ssKZ/) you'll find a way to monitor the progress of form contents. If all the field conditions are fulfilled, a submit button is shown. Maybe it's useful for you. Bare in mind that client side checking of a form may be tampered with, so you always need a server side check too, if your data need to adhere to certain requirements. In other words: client side form checks are merely usability enhancements.